# Liquid images in firefox not liquid

Tags: css, responsive-design

So I've got these images that shrink in Chrome (the browser I use to design) and fit in my responsive design quite nicely. But when I view this page in Firefox the images don't shrink from their original size. (Also IE9 has the same problem.)

I'm using the following CSS:

```
.pics img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}​
```

A jsFiddle of this is here: http://jsfiddle.net/S7ur2/

I've looked around, but haven't found a solution. If you could help me out I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of those ugly `auto` and use `width` instead of `max-width`
 http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/S7ur2/3/

```
.pics {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 15px;
}
.pics img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

Comment: In chrome the images in your example are like 5px wide and don't grow.

Comment: @elclanrs: is there no fundamental reason why we should use max-width instead of width for liquid layout images ?